# How to rearrange/tidy column in R data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose we have this data set, where `avg_1`, `avg_2` and `avg_3` repeat themselves:

```
avg_1  avg_2  avg_3  party_gender
424    242    213    RM
424    242    213    RF
424    242    213    DM
```

How can I edit this using R so that the data set looks like this (where the avg values aren't repeated, and `avg_1`, `avg_2` and `avg_3` correspond to `RM`, `RF` and `DM` respectively):

```
avg  party_gender
424  RM
242  RF
213  DM
```

Comment: df %>% select('avg' = avg_1, party_gender) where df is your dataframe

Comment: This only gives the values of avg_1.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this is a bit hacky and doesn't work nicely if you have more than just a few conditions for the avg. value:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-party_gender) %>%
  filter(party_gender == "RM" & value == 424 |
         party_gender == "RF" & value == 242 |
         party_gender == "DM" & value == 213) %>%
  mutate(name = "avg") %>% 
  pivot_wider()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  party_gender   avg
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 RM             424
2 RF             242
3 DM             213
```